# Solving a basic differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve $\frac{dx}{dt} = a + (b - 1)x$, where $a$, $b$ are constant?

I've tried pushing symbols around, but to no avail.

Comment: Do you know about separable differential equations?

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure how to separate.

Answer (score 1):

You can separate variables,
$$
\frac{dx}{a+(b-1)x}=dt.
$$
Then integrate. I leave that to you.

Comment: All right, I'll take a stab at this. I had the original equation wrong by the way; it should be $x$ and not $x^2$.

Comment: With $x$ instead of $x^2$ you could also view it as a first order linear differential equation and solve it with integrating factor. If you know that method.

Answer (score 1):

**By indeterminate constants**:

By educated guess, you can try a constant, let $A$. By substitution,

$$0=a+(b-1)A,$$then
$$A=-\frac a{b-1}.$$

You can also try an exponential, $Be^{Ct}$. Then

$$BCe^{Ct}=a+(b-1)B^{Ct}.$$

Obviously, the exponentials cancel out when $C=b-1$, whatever $B$, and you still need to compensate the constant.

Then
$$\color{green}{x(t)=Be^{(b-1)t}-\frac a{b-1}}.$$

As this is a first order differential equation, a solution with a single free constant is fine.

---

The special case $b=1$ requires separate treatment. But

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=a$$ is immediately integrated as

$$\color{green}{x(t)=at+B}.$$

---

A few solutions with $a=1$ and $x(0)=0$, for varying $b$:

[image]: