# Easy differential equation I cannot solve

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It doesn't seem to be hard, yet I cannot solve it:

$f(x)=a*f'(x)+b$

Where $a$ and $b$ are constants, $a<0$, $b>0$

Comment: separation of variables

Comment: Hi Virginia, do you know the general method for solving differential equations of the form $f'(x) + cf(x) = d$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1563877/solving-a-basic-differential-equation?rq=1

Comment: In fact I've managed to solve it(I hope): f(x) = e^((x+C)/a) + b, but what I need to know now is what is C equal to

Answer (score 1):

You have $f'(x) - \frac{1}{a}f(x) = \frac{b}{a}$. So you can use the integrating factor $e^{\int -\frac{1}{a} \, \mathrm{d}x} = e^{-\frac{x}{a}}$ so $$(e^{-\frac{x}{a}}f(x))' = \frac{b}{a}e^{-\frac{x}{a}} \Rightarrow e^{-\frac{x}{a}}f(x) = \frac{b}{a}\int e^{-\frac{x}{a}} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

Answer (score 1):

$a\frac{dy}{dx}=y-b$ where $f(x)=y$

$\implies \frac{dy}{y-b}=(1/a)dx$

On integration, $\ln|y-b|=\frac{x}{a}+c$ ; $y\ne b$ and $c\in\mathbb R$ is constant of integration.

or $y(x)=b+A.e^{x/a}$ is general solution, where $A=\pm e^c$ is non-zero real.

Moreover, $y=b$ is a lost (though not singular) solution of it.

Comment: How do I know the $C$?

Comment: @Virginia You need some additional boundary conditions to determine this

Answer (score 0):

we can rewrite the differential equations as $f=af'+b$, which can be also written as 
$af'-f=b$. This is an inhomogenous ODE with constant coefficients, so we want to solve by first finding the general solution for the homogeneous case and then adding the particular solution. This is the work.

$af'-f=0$ (homogeneous case) 
$af'=f$, with solution $f=\frac{1}{a}e^{ax}$. Notice we can just plug this back in to see that this is indeed a solution.

Now we need to handle the constant term $b$ on the right side for the inhomogenuous case. Never forget that differential equations are *equations*, so we want to find something that "works". Use $f=\frac{1}{a}e^{ax}-bx+c$. 
Since we have a constant term on the right side, the way to solve those types of inhomogenous ODEs is the form $f=bx+c$. Plug this back in and see that it works.